# Escape string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, vk

I need to escape this string somehow (with newlines):

> :-\
>   "123"
>   :-/

And get this after escaping:

> :-\\n\"123\"\n:-/

I tried this, but it's not what I needed.

```
:-\\\n/"123/"\n:-/      .replace(/"/g,'/\"')
:-\\\n/"123/"\n:-/      .replace(/"/g,'\/"')
:-\\\n\\"123\\"\n:-/    .replace(/"/g, '\\"') ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mess with replaces, use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
text = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;

text = JSON.stringify(text).slice(1, -1)

alert(text)
```

```html
<pre>
:-\
"123"
:-/
</pre>
```

Comment: @BadVolt: glad to hear it helped ;)